# HTML Formatter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, tidy

I have been looking around for a HTML formatter to incorporate with a project I am doing. I need it to be written in Javascript since I want the formatting done on the client side.

The problem is, the few that I have tried don't work very well... For example:

http://www.davidpirek.com/blog/html-beautifier-jquery-plugin : Has a problem with one of the For loops (in the cleanAsync function). Chrome says "unexpected token ILLEGAL"

JS Beautifier on GitHub : When I have links in the HTML it will put a newline character after it. The problem is, I have a period directly after the link in some cases and it will add a space between the link text and the period in the sentence. I tried poking around to fix it but I could not.

Are there any others, or does anyone have recommendations to fix the above two?

EDIT:

This is for editing code, so I just need something to tab in the lines, etc. The code output will go in a textarea.

Comment: The problem with the first one looks like that stray single-quote character in the loop. Probably just a typo by that blog author.

Comment: When I tried removing the single quote Chrome was complaining about an unexpected parenthesis character. :/

Comment: Is google's [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) an option? (It's what's used on here)

Comment: It looks like Prettify will output a DIV that is colored, but I need to take the formatted code and stick it in a textarea for editing... Maybe I can modify it?

Answer (score 1):

use https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify and pass your code to `html_beautify()` method.

Answer (score 0):

A few to look at, all have working demos:

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

http://shjs.sourceforge.net/

http://jush.sourceforge.net/

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/highlight.html