# How to display html on webpage in formatted way?

Tags: .net, html

i have to display some html content which should be in formatted way.
actually i compare two html file & now i want to display these two file content in my page with differences on page but the problem is that the content i display it's not in formatted way.
so is there any third party control or something like that for doing these?

Comment: Are you trying to display html code as plain text on a html page?  But formatted in "pretty" way?

Comment: @JonTaylor yes i trying to display html code in formatted way...

Comment: you could always use `<pre>` tags

Comment: @JonTaylor I tried that but it doesn't show tags...

Comment: can you post some sample code you are using?

Comment: <pre>
        <div>
            Test</div>
        <p>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content
            of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it
            has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
            here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing
    
        </p>
    </pre>

Comment: @JonTaylor It display plain text no <div> or <p> tag display & it's not in formatted.... like hirechy...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13660/discussion-between-bins-and-jon-taylor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

[How to format/tidy/beautify in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913355/html-formatter-tidy-beautifier-for-javascript)

[HTML Formatter in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212987/html-formatter-in-javascript)